# cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNet' using python 3.6 and opencv3.4.1

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.6

I have downloaded the source code of Opencv3.4.1 from github and I have built it from the source using CMake. Everything went very well and it's installed! 
But When I run this script: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection.py", line 52, in <module>
    net = cv.dnn.readNet(args.model, args.config, args.framework)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNet'
```

**System information (version)**

```
OpenCV => 3.4.1
Operating System / Platform => Windows 64 Bit
Python =>3.6
```

When I run `print(cv.__version__)` I get `3.4.1` But I can't find the that function or any other new features in the 3.4.1 version!

I have built from the source on Ubuntu 16.04 and on Windows 10. But still no luck! the source is downloaded from Github https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.1.zip

Does anyone has any tips?

Comment: looking at your first link it seems that it was modified a month ago. And looking at the [3.4.1 tag in github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.4.1) it was updated 2 months ago.... you may be getting changes that are not in the opencv version that you have. You may try with [master](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master) to get the latest changes or at least the changes [up to the day](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/f2440ceae68d2872a373e795d2b3168352570106) the tutorial was updated

Comment: Thanks Pablo! 
I am now building it from source (current master branche). I will let you know

Comment: @amitnair92 check my answer! Make sure you pulled the correct release from the github repository!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [api55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888688/api55) for his suggestion!

I could solve the problem by downloading the source code from the current master branche of opencv https://github.com/opencv/opencv

Comment: 0
down vote
I built from master branch too, but now how do I make it available for conda env?

Comment: During the build you have to specify the Python version (in this case your conda environment). Then it must be available for your conda env!

Answer (score 1):

change readNet function with `readNetFromDarknet` 
nb : if you have the failure no attribute named `RedNetFromDarknet` , this is because this function is implemented in `opencv_3.3.1` and greater versions.
for my case it have the same problem with `opencv_3.3.0` and i noticed that this function is not implemented in this version. That's why you should check if the version you are using contain this function.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too because I had an old version of Opencv (3.x). So, I tried `pip uninstall opencv-python` then `pip install opencv-python` and now I have the newest one (4.x) and `cv2.dnn.readNet` is now recognized.